# Using Dynamic Linq to Filter entity by datetimeoffset columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I am doing a dynamic linq using the DynamicLinq dll where-in I am sending the dynamic filter constructed like the one below

```
"CreatedDate=System.DateTimeOffset.Parse(\"2017-11-17 22:07:04.9192538 +00:00\")",
```

However, i am getting an error that System does not exist. However, I also tried the following but no luck.

```
"CreatedDate=(\"2017-11-17 22:07:04.9192538 +00:00\")",
```

But getting the below message

> Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTimeOffset' and 'String' (at index 11)

What is the right approach to filter the date time offset columns using dynamic linq and EF?

Code

```
IQueryable<T> query = Set<T>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    query = Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(query, filter);
```

Comment: Have you tried "CreatedDate.Equals(\"2017-11-17 22:07:04.9192538 +00:00\")" or '==' instead of '=' ? Also, try it statically typed first to make sure you have all of the syntax correct and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the string into a DateTimeOffset object like:

```
var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2017-11-17 22:07:04.9192538 +00:00")
```

Then you can use this:

```
query.Where("CreatedDate==DateTimeOffset(@0)", dateTime)
```